# Can I spawn a python process in a remote machine as a way to scale my compute?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, serverless, serverless-framework, ray

I'm looking to scale some compute in a python application.

I'm running this on a multi-core machine, and it scales more or less linearly with the number of processes I spawn.

I'd like to spawn additional processes in a remote machine/machines - using either Azure Functions or Containers as a service.

I came across Ray as a framework to do this, though it requires a cluster of VMs, and for my usecase a simple scaling across serverless compute to do a one-off calculation would be enough.

Any clues how I could achieve this?

I considered deploying a fastAPI app to auto-scale on Azure Container Apps that accepts a python function to execute and executes it, returning the result as a pickle-serialized object.

This kind of works, but it feels sub-optimal (not to mention the obvious security issues with a server meant to execute arbitrary python code).

Comment: Can you do what you seek via a command line perhaps via ssh? If so, you can use sub process

Comment: Have you considered a work queue system like [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html)?

Comment: Yes, I looked into ssh sup processes - they are good for running scripts but maybe I need to look into running functions - could be an answer. There is also Ray and RPyC which I'm looking into now. Not sure about Celery, I always knew it as a scheduler, but I'll have a look.